# Javascript not working in php project and user is still getting routed to php page instead of holding at current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my index.html page code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </meta>
        <title>School</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="margin:auto; width:1000px;">

            <div class="flt topblock"> <a href="" class="flt1 tp_txtplay">Play School</a>
                <br/><br/>
                <div>

                    <form id='myform' method='post' action='welcome.php' >
                        <span class="flt1 lp_txtlog">Email ID</span>
                        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="flt lp_textbox" />
                        <br />
                        <span class="flt1 lp_txtlog2">Password</span>

                        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="flt lp_textbox2" />
                        button id="submit" class='flt lp_button'>Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="ack"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my_script.js code :-

```
$("button#submit").click(function() {
    if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "")
        $("div#ack").html("Please enter both username and password");
    else
        $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),
                $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                function(data) {
                    $("div#ack").html(data);
                });

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });

});
```

and below is my welcome.php code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Wahegurug@9');
        mysql_select_db('test', $con);
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";

        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            if ($row['Username'] == $_POST['username']) {
                if ($row['Password'] == $_POST['password']) {
                    echo'login successful';
                } else {
                    echo'login failed';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Details are :- I have made this project in Netbeans 7.3 and using xampp server. I have created a simple login page and am trying to use javascript to prevent the page submitting if the wrong credentials are entered.

In my_script.js I'm using a div with id ack to show the user a success or error message.

My problem is that the user is still being redirected to welcome.php (my form's target) even if the wrong credentials are entered. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi Orangepill,I tried the below solution mentioned by you but still getting the same behaviour.Even if I leave the values blak the user gets routed to welcome.php page.So really dont know why its happening.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is prevent the default action.

Change

```
$("button#submit").click( function() {
```

to

```
$("button#submit").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Also you are explicitly calling the submit function here:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Try removing this code as well, it is likely resolving prior to the $.post call finishes

Lastly your jquery code should be wrapped in a document.ready block ...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "")
                $("div#ack").html("Please enter both username and password");
            else
                $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),
                        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                        function(data) {
                            $("div#ack").html(data);
                        });

        });
  });
```

As for your welcome.php page this would probably serve you better.

```
  <?php
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Wahegurug@9');
  mysql_select_db('test', $con);
  if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where Username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"])."'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        if ($row['Password'] == $_POST['password']) {
            echo'login successful';
            return;
        }
  }
  echo'login failed';
  ?>
```

This will only get and check the password of the user in question and will return a failure in all cases. Plus I removed the framing page markup since it is being injected into an existing page.

Comment: has the behavior changed at all? Try looking at the network in either firebug or chrome dev tools and make sure that the post is going up and what the response is.

Comment: SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
my_script.js, line 1 character 1

Comment: I got this error when i ran my local host in IE9.So can you please help why its coming

Comment: Are you including jquery in the head of the document. And if so then are you calling jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Based on the above HTML it appears that you are. Double check your reference to the jquery JS file, is located in the script directory located next to your html file?

Comment: I am using jquery in head as you can see in the index.html file code pasted above.But not sure how and why jQuery.noConflict(); function is used.

Comment: What the error message is saying is that $ doesn't exist. That means your jquery-1.8.2.min.js file isn't being loaded. Just to eliminate some issues try to replace your jquery include with `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yup.Just did that.It removed the error but still moving to welcome.php page

Comment: Can you also help me at one more place.Now the user is not getting routed to next page and also if i enter blank , I get alert on same page but in case I enter wrong credentials the crrent page gets called again and div is not loaded wih alert.So I am sure that is issue with welcome.php setup.Can you guide me how can I setup my welcome.php so that only alert gets passed to div

Comment: hey.Thanks again but the behaviour of the page is still the same.When I enter correct credentials the current page gets doubled.It means like I have a username and password block on the upper half and a same half appears on lower part.But the div does not show the message.Really strange behaviour

Comment: hey,Actually the issues is with  $("div#ack").html(data); . This is calling the whole html code of index page again and thus double the page is being shown.I commented this and it worked but still I have to update dic someway.So please help me out

Answer (score 1):

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
             $("button#submit").click(function(event) {     
            var is_send=true;   
            var username=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
                 if (username == "" || $(password == "")        
                     {
                     $("div#ack").html("Please enter both username and password");  
                     is_send=false;     
                     }
                else
                     $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),
                             $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                             function(data) {
                                 $("div#ack").html(data);
                             });    
                  if(is_send==false) 
                  {
                  return false;
                  }

             }); 
            });
```

try this, it work for me....

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this .

```
$("button#submit").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//Will prevent the default event of click


});
```

Comment: Sorry but this also did nt work.I tried but got the same results.If you want any additional information also please let me know but I really want to correct this.